# Disable GUI on Specific Monitor

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-gnome

## Description / Problem

I would like to disable the GUI on a specific monitor and have it replaced by a terminal.  I want to be able to switch control from my GUI desktop to the terminal with a specific key bind, something like Ctrl+Alt+8. I'm running `Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS` with x11.

## What I've tried

I've also tried searching for a way to lock a monitor to a specific application with no luck.

## Notes

I recognize that this may seem like a dumb request, but I only ever use this monitor for my terminal. I want this monitor to only have my terminal in it and be there on startup. I'm willing to accept that this might not be possible, and maybe for a good reason.

Comment: You might be talking about multiseat, with the other monitor being the other seat running a fbdev terminal app, except this would be complicated if you have to use the key to reattach the monitor between that and your normal seat. It would be easier to just open a terminal on that monitor and set it to always-on-top